# Application does not display anything on LCD on arm board

Tags: qt

I have cross compiled Qt 4.7.4 for an ARM board successfully. 
I have created a sample Qt application for an ARM board and cross compiled that as well.

When I run the app on the actual hardware, I do not see the UI on the LCD screen (but could see the logs provided using qDebug).

At this point, if I reboot the board, the UI of the sample app becomes visible for a second, just before the screen turns off, due to the reboot.

Do you have any suggestions regarding this problem. What could be the possible causes for this?

Regards,
Mohan

Answer (score 0):

I did solve this problem.

Need to change the backlight intensity. Set it to the maximum and UI is visible on the LCD screen.

No changes/update required anything related to Qt.